# Creating a rank 4 tensor

Tags: matrix, tensors

I am struggling with creating the rank-4 matrix T in Mathematica. The matric is defined as

$T_{i,j,k,l}= n_i n_j n_k n_l-(\delta_{i,j} n_k n_l +\delta_{i,k} n_j n_l+\delta_{i,l} n_k n_j+\delta_{j,l} n_i n_k+\delta_{j,k} n_i n_l+\delta_{k,l} n_i n_j)/6$,

Where $n$ is a vector with two components: $n=(a,b)$.

I used TensorProduct to create the matrix, but I am not sure if that is correct, and also I do not know how to add the second part with delta functions. Could someone please help me?

Here is what I did:

```
n = {a, b};
mat = TensorProduct[n, n, n, n]
mat // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second syntax of [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) and it should work like the code below, but it is yet to be checked whether each 4-length `List` as the second argument of `Transpose` exactly corresponds to your order of indexes or not

```
n = {a, b};
id4 = TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], n, n];
mat = TensorProduct[n, n, n, n] - (id4 + Transpose[id4, {1, 3, 2, 4}] + 
     Transpose[id4, {1, 4, 3, 2}] + Transpose[id4, {3, 1, 4, 2}] + 
     Transpose[id4, {3, 1, 2, 4}] + Transpose[id4, {3, 4, 1, 2}])/6
```

---

**Update**

As @WReach mentioned in the comment, two groups of indices above should indeed be corrected as below:

```
{3, 1, 4, 2} -> {2, 4, 1, 3}
{3, 1, 2, 4} -> {2, 3, 1, 4}
```

Though, the spirit of using `Transpose` is uninfluenced all the way.

Comment: +1.  I believe that the index sets 3142 and 3124 should be 2413 (jlik) and 2314 (jkil).  At least, that matches what I got using direct construction: `kd[i_,j_,k_,l_] := KroneckerDelta[i,j]n[[k]]n[[l]]; Table[n[[i]]n[[j]]n[[k]]n[[l]] - (kd[i,j,k,l]+kd[i,k,j,l]+kd[i,l,k,j]+kd[j,l,i,k]+kd[j,k,i,l]+kd[k,l,i,j])/6
, {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}, {l, 2}]`

Comment: @WReach Thx very much! After a double-check, I think your order of index is correct. BTW, I believe that your `Table`-`Part` combo deserves an individual answer rather than just a comment.